# BigQuery : How to pass a column name that has the same name as an SQL insturction

Tags: google-bigquery

Helllo,

I have a table that has an SQL instruction as a column name. I have tried the standard SQL solutions with "limit" or [limit] but they don't work.

```
SELECT
    limit
FROM
    table
```

Regards

Comment: use back-ticks - like `SELECT \`limit\` FROM table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use reserved SQL instruction words as column name, use them in backticks. Or write the table name in front:

```
select tbl.limit, `limit`
from 
(select 1 as `limit`) tbl
```